# Хранение разных сессий laravel

Tags: laravel, php, memcached, сессия

Возможно ли менять динамично, используемый для хранения сессии, драйвер?
Чтоб часть инфы хранить к примеру в файле, а часть в памяти.

Да, за ответ спасибо. Я понял и разобрался как этим пользоваться, но вот конкретный пример:
на клиенте пишем
`$(document).ready(function(){
for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/test',
            data: {key:i}
        });
    }
});`
в роутере
`Route::get('/test',function(){
    Session::put('key'.Input::get('key'), 'value'.Input::get('key'));
});
Route::get('/show', function(){
    return Session::all();
});`
заходим на host/show видим
`{"flash":{"old":[],"new":[]},"_token":"oX6IFD1Hj4nKK1tOgQa9QXnR5cFhPYeayx2DShTG","key0":"value0","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":"value4","key5":"value5","key6":"value6","key10":"value10","key11":"value11","key13":"value13","key16":"value16","key17":"value17","key19":"value19","key20":"value20","key22":"value22"}`
где 7,8,9,12,14,15,18,21,23,24,25 ???

Comment: Нет нельзя. Опишите задачу, возможно есть более грамотное решение для нее

Comment: Вот тут вопрос задавал.
http://hashcode.ru/questions/411400/php-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-memcached
Уже хз что делать.

В файл пишется, в память нет.

Стоит задача кидать на сервер несколько ajax-запросов и каждый что то должен дописать в сессию.

Comment: Вам же ответили, и ответили правильно - используйте memcache или redis. Тут добавить больше нечего. Если Вы не понимаете или не знаете, как пользоваться этими инструментами - это уже отдельный разговор. А Laravel уже имеет встроенную поддержку Redis.